# Unexpected behavior in Jenkins Pipeline Groovy: .each not iterating

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have reduced some unexpected behavior (to me) in Jenkins Pipeline groovy to the following:  Create a Jenkins Pipeline project with the following script code:

```
def a = ['a','b','c']
def ctx = [ alljobs: a ]
def say(s) {println "$s"}

@NonCPS
def fn(ctx) {
  say "ctx.alljobs=$ctx.alljobs"
  ctx.alljobs.each { j -> say "$j" }
  say "done"
}
say "before fn()"
fn(ctx)
say "after fn()"
```

When I execute this in a Groovy interpreter outside of Jenkins (less @NonCPS), I get the output I expected:

```
before fn()
ctx.alljobs=[a, b, c]
a
b
c
Done.
after fn()
```

When I run the Jenkins Pipeline job I see the following:

```
Started by user John Elion (john.elion)
[Pipeline] echo
before fn()
[Pipeline] echo
ctx.alljobs=[a, b, c]
[Pipeline] echo
after fn()
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

The .each is not executing at all (I have also seen it execute once - which is what prompted me to try to reduce to a simple code snippet), and the function is being abandoned - the say after the loop is not printed, but the say after the function returns is being executed.

I have tried wrapping various blocks in try-catch to see if an exception is occurring, but no luck.  Am I missing something?  Am I wrong to be expecting the behavior I see in the groovy interpreter outside of Jenkins?

Pipeline bug?  Or am I missing something?

I am executing on Jenkins v2.44.  It is a tightly locked down environment; I know it is running on some kind of Linux; I believe I have workflow-cps 'Pipeline: Groovy' v2.26, and I'm not sure which other pipeline or other plugins are relevant.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is that "say" needs to be @NonCPS.  Then it works as expected.

The reason it looks like an exception is occurring is because @NonCPS is implemented to throw an exception which is caught and handled internally.  See https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/master/README.md for the technical details.

It seems the interpreter ought to raise a user-visible error when a @NonCPS function calls a CPS-enabled function, rather than silently aborting the function and moving on with the pipeline...

Comment: One of several situations where Jenkins doesn't provide enough information (or any) if you've done something wrong in your script.